# iOS Popup broken after converting to ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey I converted my project to ARC automatically and the only thing I had to fix was that Xcode changed array that had a size of [8] to [4] (still don't know what was going on there)

However, I now realized I got another problem: every time I hit a button in my Popup, the app crashed if it is linked to an IBAction. If I remove the reference to the header and main file, the button is clickable, but as soon as i assign it to a method (even if the method is empty), the whole app jut freezes/crashes.

This is how I initiate my popup:

```
PopUpViewController *popViewController =
[[PopUpViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"PopUpViewController" bundle:nil];

[popViewController setTitle:@"This is a popup view"];
[popViewController showInView:self.view
                                 animated:YES];
popViewController.view.center=self.view.center;
```

Pretty basic stuff, I ripped it off a tutorial I found online. My header is this:

```
@interface PopUpViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)baa:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIButton *ba; // I was trying to add those buttons as properties here
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *kl; //but no luck whatsoever

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *popUpView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *ppp;

- (IBAction)openSomething:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)openYoutube:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)openFacebook:(id)sender;

- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

And my main

```
#import "PopUpViewController.h"

@interface PopUpViewController ()

@end 

@implementation PopUpViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

} 
    return self;
}
- (void)showAnimate
{
  // not important for this question
}

- (void)removeAnimate
{
  // shortened
}

- (IBAction)baa:(id)sender{
//    NSLog(@"asd"); I commented it out, but even an empty method kills the app
// only if I leave a button unassigned to any method, the app "survives" a button click

}

- (IBAction)openSomething:(id)sender
{
   // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.de"]];
}

- (IBAction)openYoutube:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/"]];
}

- (IBAction)openFacebook:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/"]];

}

- (void) doSomething{
 // also tried an empty method with a "new" name over here to eliminate any caching errors, no luck   
}

- (IBAction)closePopup:(id)sender {
    [self removeAnimate];
}

- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [aView addSubview:self.view];
    if (animated) {
        [self showAnimate];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.0];
    self.popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.popUpView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.popUpView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.2f, 0.2f);


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


@end
```

Any ideas what I could do different? I referenced everything to everything else possible now and I don't even know how it looked before anymore, but I somehow think it has something to do with the referencing.

Thanks a lot in advance, Alex

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out on my own:

In the header of my main ViewController I added

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) PopUpViewController *popViewController;
```

Which still fired the crash. But then I adjusted the popup "opening" block to

```
_popViewController =
            [[PopUpViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"PopUpViewController" bundle:nil];                 

            [_popViewController setTitle:@"This is a popup view"];
            [_popViewController showInView:self.view
                                 animated:YES];
            _popViewController.view.center=self.view.center;
```

(added the underscores) and now it's working perfectly again.

Actually I am curious why it worked before but I am not going to investigate this any further.